# How to parse string into date time format?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have string having value "August-25-2011". How can I parse that into Datetime format?

Comment: If you just put your last sentence in google you'd have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    your_date, 
    "MMMM-dd-yyyy" , 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I tried this one but I am getting exception which is :-Method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: @user624201: what? You tagged this question as C#, so why I read SQL now? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You could try doing the conversion outside of the LINQ to SQL expression then passing it in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("August-25-2011");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
    your_date, 
    "MMMM-dd-yyyy" , 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

```
DateTime parsedDate;
string pattern = "MMMM-dd-yyyy" ;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate)
```

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified array of formats,
>   culture-specific format information, and style. The format of the
>   string representation must match at least one of the specified formats
>   exactly. The method returns a value that indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.